# How do I teleport between my base and the closest I have traveled to the center of the universe

Tags: no-mans-sky

Say I want to go back to my base every now and then but also continue travelling to the center of the universe. How do I make sure I can travel back to where I got to after visiting my base.

Currently I am building a new base station on a planet before teleporting back to my main base. The problem is this costs resources and I have to remember the name of the system I came from.

It does seem like you can teleport to recently visited systems via a teleporter but none of these give an indication on which one is closest to the center of the universe.

Comment: *"you can teleport to recently visited systems"* - you already answered your question. Or are you asking for a [maximum number](https://www.reddit.com/r/NoMansSkyTheGame/comments/9h6bi5/max_destinations_on_basespace_station_teleport/)? tl;dr: it's unlimited. Or you want to know which one was last? Not sure but check the sorting, I think it's "most recent visited on top", otherwise you have to check system names and where they are. Hint: you can name discovered system in a way to be able to distinguish direction.

Comment: Ideally a means of identifying at a glance which system is closet to the center when I  want to pick up the "get to the center of the universe" quest line. Good to know the teleporter destination count its unlimited though. I want to avoid having to manually taking note of my closest system.

Comment: @kenjara Please consider checking the existing answer as the accepted one if it fulfills your requirement. If not, you may want to write a comment under it to explain why.

Answer (score 1):

Besides using the Teleporter located in your local [Space Station](https://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Space_station), you could also make it a point (while you can) to "[Rename and Upload](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/356405/is-system-planet-etc-naming-based-on-first-to-discover-or-first-to-upload)" solar systems/planets that you discover, and use a naming convention or just wild jibber-jabber so that you know it's yours.  If you have a full fledged base on one of these planets, it will also show the little Dome icon to indicate that you have a base there, presumably with a Teleporter hooked up to a power source.

Also, when creating a base, you are able to name your base.  This helps even further when teleporting to one of your bases because regardless of what planet/solar system it is in, you will always control what it is named.  So as for noting which ones are closer to the center, you can just call it Base1 (furthest away), Base2 (closer), Base3 (I think you get my point).

I hope this helps you out [Traveler](https://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Traveller)!

Comment: While this can be done by taking notes whether it would be in the name of discoveries or an actual notebook I was after something internal to the game that would manage the situation for you.