# Is system/planet/etc naming based on first to discover or first to upload?

Tags: no-mans-sky

If I am the first to discover a solar system, planet, fauna, etc. and I never upload it, is someone else able to come along and upload a name for it before me?

Comment: Which edition of the game are you asking about? I have experience in the PS4 edition, but I know the PC edition has completely different mechanisms for such things.

Comment: Oh, I'm playing on PC. Had no idea there were differences between the platforms aside from different servers.

Comment: In server-client games clients are never trusted. So it's unlikely there is a date/time of discovery when you click submit button some time later or if your submit with earlier date would overwrite data of some other player who happens to discover it later. More likely it's a simple process where first to click submit is served, rest is synchronized to already submit name.

Comment: @shelby115 yeah, there are major differences in the way multiplayer is handled.

Comment: On the PS4, it is whoever first made the discovery, whether it was uploaded or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For PC, yes, if you don't upload your findings, someone else can come and take credit for your discoveries.

I can speak from experience. In the new BEYOND update, traveling to the Anomaly allows other players to teleport to your base up using the on-ship teleporter system. One time, after a visit to Nada and Polo, I saw another player had come to visit my base. At first I thought this was kinda cool, but then I realized the player uploaded *my home planet* for his own gain AND renamed it after himself. He then started doing the same for all the animals he could find on the planet. (I don't usually upload discoveries because I don't need the nanites and encountering another player during normal gameplay is typically impossible.) Heck, he even started building a base of his own *right next to mine!!!* So rude. Obviously I was upset, so I packed up my base and moved to a different system.

Comment: This is the exact reason I asked this question, wanted to make sure this exact thing never happened lol.

Comment: To tease him (or have a little back) I would have built a dirt-dome encasing his base. (Only works if he is nearby so the state of the terrain gets saved for him as well.)